# Angular directive unit testing - scope values not showing up in compiled result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This should be either caused by something dumb on my end, or maybe using an old version of angular tools.

"angular": "1.2.12",
"angular-route": "~1.2.7",
"angular-loader": "1.2.x",
"angular-mocks": "1.2.12",

So I expect to see scope vals interpolated into the compiled directive at some point, but they are not.
UNIT TEST

```
var expect = chai.expect;
var assert = chai.assert;
beforeEach(module('myapp'));
beforeEach(module('mytemplates'));

describe('Testing notifications directive', function() {
    var scope, elem;
    var html = '<notifications></notifications>';
    beforeEach(function(){
        inject(function($compile, $rootScope, _tableService_) {
            console.log('beforeEach')
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            scope.testing = "i'm testing";
            scope.inner = {testing: "i'm inner testing"};
            element = $compile(html)(scope);
            console.log('Pre digest['+element+']');
            scope.$digest();
        });
    });

    it('should render a notifications element', function() {
        console.log('In unit test['+element+']');
});
```

DIRECTIVE

```
 var notificationsControllerName = 'NotificationController';
    function notificationsController($rootScope, $scope, $interval, tableService) {
      $scope.tableService = new tableService();
      function reloadTables(){
          $scope.tableService.load(function(data) {
              $scope.problems = _.filter(data.tables, function(t) {return t.exception;});
              _.each($scope.problems, function(notification){
                  notification.elapsed = (Date.now() - new Date(Date.parse(notification.created))).valueOf() / 1000 / 60;
              });
          });
      }

      // when this directive is on display, the controller will poll
      $scope.cancelPoll = $interval(reloadTables, 15000);

      // when a user logs out, the directive is destroyed and the poll will stop
      $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
          $interval.cancel($scope.cancelPoll);
      });
    }

    myApp.directive('notifications', function() {
        return {
            controller: notificationsController,
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'partials/notifications.html',
        };
    });

    myApp.controller(notificationsControllerName, notificationsController);
```

RAW PARTIAL

Just testing: {{testing}} Inner.testing are you there?: {{inner.test}}

OUTPUT
    beforeEach
    Pre digest[]
    In unit test[Just testing:  Inner.testing are you there?: ]

Comment: Could you post the directive too please

Comment: OK I've posted the directive